# I'm not receiving the 20.10 updates

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager, 20.10

Every time I try to update my system I get the message `All packages are up to date`. I think something goes wrong during the upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10.

My process to verify updates is: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. But in the first step I don't reach the updates.

This is my sources file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ groovy main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ groovy main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ groovy-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ groovy-security main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://sft.if.usp.br/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the first step I don't reach the updates"?

Comment: When I use the first command, in a normal situation I get a number of packages to update, but in this instalation dont.

Comment: Maybe there are no updates because of the holidays. So what does it show?

Comment: Right! I'll wait till January 15th. Thank you guys!